# Find actual path of webcontent

Tags: java, file, jsp, tomcat, file-upload

Im doing a small webb application in JSP which needs to have a file upload function.

Problem is that I cant find out how to get the relative path to my webcontents folder.
I need a dynamic way to get there so I can save the files in a folder relative to that path.

So far I have tried:

```
  String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
  String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
  String realPath = request.getRealPath();
  String servletPath = request.getServletPath();
```

None of them gives the actual WebContents path.
I guess there is one method I have overlooked but cant find out which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that! First, `getRealPath` works only if your webapp is expanded and second if you redeploy your app, the entire upload is wiped out.

Comment: That seems like a hughe problem. But how should I do? I have been given the suggestion not to save images as blobs in mysql but now that is the only possible solution I can see.

Comment: No, it isn't. First, define a property in a properties file or JNDI var to a writable location outside of the webapp. Write a servlet which serves files from that location. You do not need to start from scratch. Check Tomcat's  `DefaultServlet` and alter that. Set the base dir in the `init` method serve your files.

Comment: Thank you for making me notice it.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
```

---

- [`servletContext.getRealPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: It works. This might be a silly question but can you explain why it is: C:\Users\Einar\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\webapp\  When the files in the filesystem is placed in C:\Users\Einar\git\webApp\webapp\WebContent\

Comment: Could it be that I run it as an Eclips project that makes the folders behave like that?

Comment: it shows the path from where server is serving not the path of your source code